# How to setup redux persist for offline storage in React Native?

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-toolkit, asyncstorage, redux-persist

I used redux persist with asyncstorage for offline data, but after i clear my app (like swipe right to delete it from the processes in my android phone), my data is gone the next time i open the app again.

Here is the relevant code:

```
// src/reduxActions/store.ts
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { combineReducers, Store } from 'redux';
import {
  Persistor,
  persistStore,
  persistReducer,
} from 'redux-persist'
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import AuthReducer from './auth/reducer';
import ItemReducer from './item/reducer';
import autoMergeLevel1 from 'redux-persist/lib/stateReconciler/autoMergeLevel1';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  auth: AuthReducer,
  item: ItemReducer,
});

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: AsyncStorage,
  whitelist: [],
  storageReconciler: autoMergeLevel1,
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>;

let store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: false,
    }),
});

export function getStore(): Store<RootState> {
  return store;
}

export const persistor = persistStore(store);
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
```

```
// src/reduxActions/item/reducer.ts
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { Item } from 'models/item';
import { createItem, getItems, updateItem, deleteItem } from './actions';

interface ItemState {
  items: {
    [index: string]: Item,
  }
  itemIds: string[],
  offlineItems: {
    [index: string]: Item,
  },
  lastOfflineItemId: string,
}

const initialState: ItemState = {
  items: {},
  itemIds: [],
  offlineItems: {},
  lastOfflineItemId: '0',
}

const itemSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'item',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    createOfflineItem(state, action) {
      const id = (parseInt(state.lastOfflineItemId)+1).toString();
      const item = {
        "id": id,
        "createdAt": Date.now(),
      }
      state.offlineItems[id] = { ...item, ...action.payload };
      state.lastOfflineItemId = id;
    },
    toggleOfflineIsFavorite(state, action) {
      state.offlineItems[action.payload.id].isFavorite = action.payload.isFavorite;
    },
    editOfflineItem(state, action) {
      state.offlineItems[action.payload.id] = {
        ...state.offlineItems[action.payload.id],
        ...action.payload,
      };
    },
    deleteOfflineItem(state, action) {
      delete state.offlineItems[action.payload];
    }
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(createItem.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.items[action.payload.id] = action.payload;
      state.itemIds.unshift(action.payload.id);
    })
    builder.addCase(getItems.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.items = action.payload.results.reduce(function(map: { [index: string]: Item }, item: Item) {
        map[item.id] = item;
        return map;
      }, {});
      state.itemIds = action.payload.results.map((item: Item) => item.id);
    })
    builder.addCase(updateItem.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.items[action.payload.id] = action.payload;
    })
    builder.addCase(deleteItem.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.itemIds = state.itemIds.filter(id => id != action.payload);
      delete state.items[action.payload];
    })
    builder.addDefaultCase((state) => {
      return state;
    })
  },
})

const { actions, reducer } = itemSlice;
export const { createOfflineItem, toggleOfflineIsFavorite, editOfflineItem, deleteOfflineItem } = actions;

export default reducer;
```

Here is the complete code: https://www.github.com/roumanite/wmi-mobile

I want to be able to store offline data that will never go away, not with a phone restart and can also be backup & synced. I guess it will go away only if uninstalled & cleared completely

How can I fix this? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can update const persistConfig object:

```
 const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: AsyncStorage,
  whitelist: ['auth', 'item'],
  storageReconciler: autoMergeLevel1,
};
```

Comment: Please provide more information about your answering code and format it properly.